# Joined Filtered Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to count a small subset of points in a table that are within a polygon and add the count as an attribute of the geometries.

Is there a way to add a where clause to the `LEFT JOIN` below to avoid having to use the temporary table? I'd prefer the temp table solution below to a CTE i think for the sake of clarity. Performance isn't really and issue for this.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS libraries;
CREATE TEMP TABLE libraries AS(SELECT ID, osm_id, geom FROM received.osm_pois_p opp WHERE fclass = 'library');

CREATE INDEX sindx_libraries ON libraries USING gist(geom);
ANALYZE libraries;

UPDATE automated.trip_potential_hex 
SET libraries = total_count 
FROM  (
    SELECT 
        tph.ID,
        COUNT(libraries.geom) AS total_count
    FROM automated.trip_potential_hex tph 
    LEFT JOIN
        libraries 
    ON st_contains(tph.geom, libraries.geom)
    GROUP BY tph.ID) count_source
WHERE trip_potential_hex.ID = count_source.ID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why just don't move view query to a left join sub-query?

```
UPDATE automated.trip_potential_hex 
SET libraries = total_count 
FROM  (
    SELECT 
        tph.ID,
        COUNT(libraries.geom) AS total_count
    FROM automated.trip_potential_hex tph 
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT ID, osm_id, geom FROM received.osm_pois_p opp WHERE fclass = 'library') libraries 
    ON st_contains(tph.geom, libraries.geom)
    GROUP BY tph.ID) count_source
WHERE trip_potential_hex.ID = count_source.ID;
```

Second way is to rewrite your join clause like:

```
UPDATE automated.trip_potential_hex 
SET libraries = total_count 
FROM  (
    SELECT 
        tph.ID,
        COUNT(libraries.geom) AS total_count
    FROM automated.trip_potential_hex tph 
    LEFT JOIN
        received.osm_pois_p libraries 
    ON st_contains(tph.geom, libraries.geom) AND libraries.fclass = 'library'
    GROUP BY tph.ID) count_source
WHERE trip_potential_hex.ID = count_source.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

First step: create a temp VIEW instead of a table. (you won't need the index, and the view will be inlined):

---

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW libraries AS
 SELECT ID, osm_id, geom
 FROM received.osm_pois_p opp 
 WHERE fclass = 'library'
 ;
```